# what and how does happens-before happen in c++0x

Tags: c++, multithreading

Can you please explain the "happens-before" ordering on an atomic that is shared between two threads? Consider thread "Read" and thread "write", both of which shared an atomic boolean variable x. Read thread simply reads the value of x, and write thread simply writes the value to x. Given that scheduler can run these threads in any order, how does c++ ensure sequentially consistent ordering between two threads?

Comment: The answer to this is fairly involved. You can either read the standard that formally defines the C++ memory model, or another good option is in the book [_C++ Concurrency in Action_](http://www.amazon.com/C-Concurrency-Action-Practical-Multithreading/dp/1933988770) section 5.3. The amazon preview shows some of that section and that may be enough for you.

Answer (score 2):

The rule is that if one thread writes to an atomic variable and another thread reads that variable **and** sees the value that was written you have a happens-before relation. That, in turn implies that values written in the first thread before the write to the atomic variable are visible to the second thread after it reads the atomic variable and sees the value that was written.

To use an atomic variable for synchronization you have to do something like this:

```
int i = 0;
atomic<bool> ready;

// thread 1:
i = 3;
ready = true;

// thread 2:
while (!ready)
    ;  /* busy wait */
std::cout << i << '\n'; // writes "3" to cout
```

Comment: In your example, if you make i as atomic<int> and dont use the boolean ready, then  there is no guarantee if read thread will run first or write thread would run. In this case, is there a still a happens-before relationship? Also, it seems like you are enforcing the happens before relationship by creating a guard (while ! ready).   I was thinking that happens-before does not require a programming intervention like a guard. besides you could achieve same results on x86_64 with gcc and making bool ready as volatile

Comment: On further thought, does happens-before mean that if you code in such a way, that it looks sequential to programmer, for example, the way you put a guard(while ! ready), then software and hardware would ensure that it actually happens in that order, in other words, code is not reordered either by compiler or cpu

Comment: @Jimm No, simply reading `atomic<int> i` would not ensure that the write happened first. (How would that be implemented? Reading from an atomic blocks until the next atomic write?) Instead, if by chance you do read `3` then there is a happens-before relation and you know the write occurred. The `while(!ready)` code is a guard and is needed because synchronization does not occur until the expected value is actually observed. As for `volatile`, some implementations have imbued `volatile` with atomic semantics even though that is not in the C++ spec and is not portable.

Comment: @Jimm If you do synchronization properly and use only the sequential consistency memory order then a program will appear to have a single total order and will appear to be sequential. That doesn't mean code _isn't_ reordered, but any such reordering will not be detectable. Consider; modern processors already do out-of-order execution, but at the end everything is patched together so that you can't tell. Establishing all the necessary _happens-before_ relations between operations on different threads allows the same sort of trick to be pulled with multiple threads.